# scrambled json response in android

Tags: java, android, json

The reponse sent by server is like:

```
{
"data": {
    "table": {
        "0": {
            "pay_date": "2017-04-28",
            "status": "Paid",
            "bill_date": "2017-04-27",
        },
        "1": {
            "pay_date": "2017-02-02",
            "status": "Paid",
            "bill_date": "2017-01-27",
        },
        "2": {
            "pay_date": "2016-10-28",
            "status": "Paid",
            "bill_date": "2016-10-27",
        },
        "3": {
            "pay_date": "2016-07-26",
            "status": "Paid",
            "bill_date": "2016-07-26",
        },
        "4": {
            "pay_date": "2015-12-30",
            "status": "Paid",
            "bill_date": "2015-12-29",
        },
        "5": {
            "pay_date": "2015-08-03",
            "status": "Paid",
            "bill_date": "2015-07-27",
            "service_details": "Installation charge"
        },
        "6": {
            "pay_date": "2015-08-03",
            "status": "Paid",
            "bill_date": "2015-07-27",
        },
        "search": "0",
        "page": "10",
        "filter": "0"
    }
},
"status": "1"
```

}

but in tablets i get response like:

```
{"data":{"table":{"3":{"pay_date":"2016-07-26","status":"Paid","bill_date":"2016-07-26","2":{"pay_date":"2016-10-28","status":"Paid","bill_date":"2016-10-27","1":{"pay_date":"2017-02-02","status":"Paid","bill_date":"2017-01-27","0":{"pay_date":"2017-04-28","status":"Paid","bill_date":"2017-04-27","6":{"pay_date":"2015-08-03","status":"Paid","bill_date":"2015-07-27","search":"0","page":"10","5":{"pay_date":"2015-08-03","status":"Paid","bill_date":"2015-07-27","4":{"pay_date":"2015-12-30","status":"Paid","bill_date":"2015-12-29","filter":"0"}},"status":"1"}
```

can anyone tell me why tablets are interpreting response like this.However, in mobile phones i get the actual response.

Comment: If you rely on the order of numeric keys, use an `Array` (`[]`), not an `Object` (`{}`)

Comment: As @AluanHaddad said u need to use ARRay if u care about order

Answer (score 0):

It should not be the case. The JSON data retrieved from the server, should be same in both the cases whether you are getting it in mobile or in tablets.